# F# Traversing tree to make specific set

Tags: f#, tree

So I'm sitting with this problem that I can't seem to get my head around in a sensible way. What I'm trying to achieve here is that I have a function `descriptionOf os t` that takes an `Outcome list`, `os`, and a `Tree`, which is`t`, and returns a `Description` using the helper function `descriptionOf'`. That works quite alright and feeding it with the Outcome list: `let outcomeTest = [F;S]` and the tree:
`let testTree = Branch(">2",0.67, Branch(">3",0.5, Leaf "A", Leaf "B"),Branch(">3",2.5, Leaf "C", Leaf "D"))` gives me the following result:

`([(F, ">2"); (S, ">3")], 0.825, "C")`.

Now, as you can see, I've begun making `allDescriptions` which should take a `Tree` and return a `Set<Description>` but I can't the for love of me figure out how to make this set. I've been fiddling with the idea of reusing `descriptionOf` but the problem the way I see it, is that I don't have an `os` to give it, but only a `tree t`. I'm imagining the expected outcome by making the `Set<Description>` on `testTree` would be something like this: 
`set: [([(S,">2");(S,">3")], 0.335, "A"); ([(S,">2");(F,">3")], 0.335, "B");
     ([(F,">2");(S,">3")], 0.165, "C"); ([(F,">2");(F,">3")], 0.165, "D")]`.

I hope my question makes sense! Any hints greatly appreciated.

```
type Outcome  = | S | F
type Sample   = Outcome list    
type Tree = | Branch of string * float * Tree * Tree
            | Leaf of string
type Description = ((Sample * string) list * float * string)  

let rec descriptionOf' = function 
| (os, Branch(ds, p, tl, tr), (dsl, dp, s)) when List.length os > 1 && os.Head = F -> descriptionOf' (os.Tail, tr, (dsl @ [(os.Head, ds)], dp * (1.0 - p), ""))
| (os, Branch(ds, p, tl, tr), (dsl, dp, s)) when List.length os > 1 && os.Head = S -> descriptionOf' (os.Tail, tl, (dsl @ [(os.Head, ds)], dp * (p), ""))
| (os, Branch(ds, p, Leaf l1, Leaf l2), (dsl, dp, s)) when List.length os = 1 && os.Head = F -> (dsl @ [(os.Head, ds)], dp * (1.0 - p), l2)
| (os, Branch(ds, p, Leaf l1, Leaf l2), (dsl, dp, s)) when List.length os = 1 && os.Head = S -> (dsl @ [(os.Head, ds)], dp * (p), l1)
| _ -> failwith "Not a correct sample"

let descriptionOf os t = 
if isSample(os, t) = false then failwith "Not a correct sample" else
    descriptionOf'(os, t, ([], 1.0, ""))

let allDescriptions = Set.empty.Add() // What should this do?
```

Comment: Not really sure to understand but first you can write `descriptionOf'` a lot simpler by user pattern matching rather than with guard clause : desconstruct `os` into `[F]` or `[S]` for the base cases and into `F :: tail` or `S :: tail` for the recursive ones. Also for all descriptions it seems you need to "loop" through all combination of `F` and `S` of size `Tree depth`.